# Azure "role discovery data is unavailable" error when switching from IISExpress to full IIS

Tags: azure

I have an azure solution configured with one MVC4 web role, and two back-end web roles. I've been testing this on IISExpress, using internal http endpoints. This works well. I now want to test tcp endpoints, as those are what we will probably be using on Azure live, so I've changed the deployment option to use full IIS, since as I understand it, IISExpress does not support tcp bindings. I haven't yet made any changes to the endpoints, or altered anything else about the deployment. This results in a failure of the roleenvironment to initialize, and the 'role discover data is unavailable error'. I have this in the output window:

```
\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client\v4.0_4.99.2.0__31bf3856ad364e3 
\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the   
debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'w3wp.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\msshrtmi  
\1.7.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\msshrtmi.dll'
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100 : Role environment . INITIALIZING
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100 : Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED.  
HResult=-2147467259
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in    
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll
```

All my instances are visible, both as sites under IIS and in the compute emulator. I don't see anything unusual in the emulator diagnostics, which look like this for the MVC4 web role, and similar for the WCF services:

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment17(123).Azure.Web.Test.0
[fabric] Role state Unhealthy
[Diagnostics]: UpdateState(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo,    
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration, )
[Diagnostics]: Acquired mutex
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\5911e3b3-15ce-4b36-ab50-
f04dda461e60\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: D:\Work\CLIENTS\Test\Solutions\Test\Azure\csx\Debug\roles\Web.Test
\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources
\5911e3b3-15ce-4b36-ab50-f04dda461e60\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile 
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\5911e3b3-15ce-4b36-ab50-f04dda461e60\directory
\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\User\AppData
\Local\dftmp\Resources\5911e3b3-15ce-4b36-ab50-f04dda461e60\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-38fb5936e7b14b058ae4a7c0b516945d 
-InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-38fb5936e7b14b058ae4a7c0b516945d -parent 15308 -events
[Diagnostics]: Creating config channel server
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-38fb5936e7b14b058ae4a7c0b516945d is 
signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-38fb5936e7b14b058ae4a7c0b516945d after the agent 
is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 15308 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[fabric] Role state Started
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()
```

Any idea what's causing this? Are there further configuration steps to get full IIS working?

Some more details about my environment:

Win 7 x64 | IIS 7.5 | Latest release of Azure SDK

Comment: Where did you encounter this error? According to the diagnostics trace, the role is successfully started. Please try to debug your application to see if you can find more information.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. I have a controller which uses the following code at the beginning of a call: var endpoints = RoleEnvironment.Roles["UtilitiesRole"].Instances.Select(i => i.InstanceEndpoints["HttpInternal"]).ToArray(); - this works fine as long as I host in IISExpress. If I switch to full IIS7.5, it fails, with the error described above.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? If yes, how?

Comment: No, never did. Ended up just using http on that project and testing with iis express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand your problem, I created a MVC4 Web Role with HTTP/80 and Internal-HTTP (port-auto) endpoint and two Worker Role with internal TCP endpoints. I setup the following in each worker role:

```
var endpoints = RoleEnvironment.Roles["WorkerRole1"].Instances.Select(i => i.InstanceEndpoints["EndPoint11"]).ToArray();

var endpoints = RoleEnvironment.Roles["WorkerRole2"].Instances.Select(i => i.InstanceEndpoints["EndPoint12"]).ToArray();
```

And the following in MVC4 HomeController:

```
var endpoints = RoleEnvironment.Roles["MVCWebRole1"].Instances.Select(i => i.InstanceEndpoints["HttpInternal"]).ToArray();
```

I could run this scenario both with IISExpress and IIS7.5 without any problem.

If you just create a helloworld VS2010 solution (including your full configuration) which exhibit the problem, and share here, I sure can take a look and find a fix for you.

Comment: My current configuration is different from yours. I have the MVC role and two web roles (not workers), listening on internal http ports. I'm on a deadline at the moment but as soon as I can, I'll put together the hello-world solution that you suggest, and report back. For now, as long as I host in IISExpress, everything works ok.